# Does anyone have a UserDetails Service Example for Spring Cloud OAuth2 and Active Directory?

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring Cloud (Edgeware.SR3) OAuth2 Authorization server configured with Custom JWT tokens. I'm getting an IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required error when I hit the token_refresh endpoint.

Does anyone have an example of doing a UserDetails Service for Active Directory for this scenario?   I presume the call for refreshing the token is actually checking against AD if the user is still valid such as not disabled since last successful login.

Not shown is I'm also doing integrations to AWS Cognito in the custom token enhancer which is also all working.  Just the refresh token is what remains.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${ldap.domain}")
private String DOMAIN;

@Value("${ldap.url}")
private String URL;

@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    return provider;
}

}
--------
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Autowired
public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
    super();
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Value("${signing.key}")
private String signingKey;


@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(){
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
    return accessTokenConverter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore(){
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(){
    final DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("${client.id}")
            .secret("${client.secret}")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token","authorization_code","client_credentials")
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 *24)
            .scopes("xx","xx")
            .autoApprove("xxxx")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
}

@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints){

    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
            Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(),accessTokenConverter()));

    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET,HttpMethod.POST)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Override//oauth/check_token?token={access_token}
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    super.configure(security);
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer(){
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}

}
```